# K-homology of Cantor set and abelian AF-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, k-homology

This may be a standard question answered in a book, or article. I don't know. I know that there exist related results with $\lim^1$-sequences (Rosenberg and Schochet).

What is

$KK(C_0(X),\mathbb{C})$

for $X =$ Cantor set?

What is it more generally when $C_0(X)$ is an abelian AF-algebra?

My only question is, are these homology groups mostly UNCOUNTABLE?

Note that, for example,

$KK(\oplus_{n=1}^\infty  \mathbb{C} , \mathbb{C}) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$

is uncountable.

Comment: Have you got access to Higson and Roe's book? I haven't got my copy to hand, but that is the first place I would look.

Comment: I know almost nothing about KK-theory, but it seems to me that uncountability would follow from the fact that every infinite metrizable Stone space has $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ as a retract.

Comment: Isn't it just the dual group of K$_0 (A)$ (here $A = C(X)$, but could be any C*-algebra)? That is, Hom$(K_0(A),Z)$ (since K$_0 C = Z$). For $X$ a Cantor set, this is uncountable.

Comment: And because $K_0(A)$ is free on countably many generators (if $A = C(X)$ where $X$ is Cantor), its dual is the product.

Comment: @David: Maybe you could explain this with dual = $Hom(K_0(A),Z)$. When is it so and why (ok one explanation is the main answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Handelman already pointed out, by continuity of $K$-theory we obtain that $K_0(C(X)) \cong \bigoplus_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ and $K_1(C(X)) = 0$. Since $C(X)$ is commutative, it lies in the Bootstrap class of $KK$-theory (see Blackadar, "Operator algebras", section V.1.5.2, p. 414). In particular, the universal coefficient theorem holds for $C(X)$ (see V.1.5.8, p. 416 in Blackadar), i.e.
$$
 0 \to Ext^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(K_*(C(X)), K_*(\mathbb{C})) \to KK_*(C(X),\mathbb{C}) \to Hom(K_*(C(X)),K_*(\mathbb{C})) \to 0
$$
is exact and the map $\delta$ from Ext to KK has degree $1$, the map $\gamma$ from KK to Hom has degree $0$. Since $K_*(C(X))$ is free, we obtain that $\gamma$ is an isomorphism. This yields
$$
KK(C(X),\mathbb{C}) = KK_0(C(X),\mathbb{C}) \cong Hom(K_0(C(X)), \mathbb{Z}) = \prod_{\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} ,
$$
which is uncountable.

If $A$ is a commutative AF-algebra, then we have $K_1(A) = 0$ and $A$ also lies in the Bootstrap class (because it is commutative), so we still obtain an isomorphism 
$$
KK_0(A,\mathbb{C}) \cong Hom(K_0(A), \mathbb{Z})
$$
in this case. Since $K_0(A)$ is the direct limit over countable abelian groups, it should itself be countable again (feel free to correct me if I am wrong here). Therefore $KK(A,\mathbb{C})$ should be at most uncountable.

Comment: Bitte, nur ein N am hinten.

Comment: @DavidHandelman: Whoops. I am sorry. Unfortunately, writing "man" with double N is a reflex you easily develop in Germany.

Comment: @Ulrich: Very good answer, thank you very much! Thanks also to the others who commented on this.

Comment: PS: my question was: are most cases of $C_0(X)$ uncountable? (not: at most uncountable).